# (App in background) Firing an action at some date

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'd like to set a date where a method is called, even if my application runs in the background. Is that possible ?

I tried `NSTimer`, with which I can set a firing `NSDate`. Yet this doesn't work if the app is not in the foreground.

After some research, I've seen that Apple doesn't allow NSTimers to run in the background, so I guess I would have to find a workaround. I don't actually want my method to be called over and over with a time interval. I just want it to be called once, at a date I choose.
(For information, the method I want to call doesn't need any GUI (it just launches the iPod)).

Do you know any way to do that ? (if needed, I can run my app on a jailbroken iPhone).

Answer (score 0):

[UILocalNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is your friend!
It's available in iOS 4.0+ though.

Comment: Hmmmm... Thanks, I had seen that before, but I figured it was only able to display a message (and some other stuff like adding a badge to your app's icon), I didn't understand it was also able to lauch any method in my app. I will make investigation on `UILocalNotification` though...

Comment: @Daladim, you are correct, you will have to get the user to open the app from the notification where the method is performed, you can't do it without user interaction. (at least this is true on a non jailbroken device). If it's a short time, about 10 minutes, I forget the exact limit but its definitely less than a day if not an hour, then you can use the task completion api.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is actually **running** in the background, `NSTimer` should work just fine.

If you don't need app store approval, simply claim you're doing background audio (see [UIBackgroundModes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)) and play a silent audio file to keep your app alive.

Note that there are some things, such as calling OpenGL functions, that will get you killed instantly in the background, however, most APIs work just fine.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it, that doesn't sound bad. (I actually saw that workaround, but I thought there might have been an easier way since I don't need timers to fire regularly, just once is enough for me) But won't it drain my battery too much? I'd like to use my app as a kind of alarm clock. It should "sleep" (or run while playing a mute sound) in the background all night until it performs a method in the morning...